# TestContext is null

Tags: .net, asp.net, unit-testing, testing, visual-studio

Pretty simple test:

```
[TestClass]
public class MyTestClass
{
    private TestContext _testContext;
    protected TestContext TestContext
    {
        get { return _testContext; }
        set { _testContext = value; }
    }

    [TestMethod]
    [HostType("ASP.NET")]
    [UrlToTest("http://localhost/MyPage.aspx")]
    public void TestMyPage()
    {
        Assert.IsNotNull(TestContext);
    }
}
```

Fails... Now I am using VS2008 Development edition. Is there any possibility to fix this? Or I need to have a Test (or Team Suite) edition?

Thanks.

P.S. Access to TestContext object is required to have access to it's RequestedPage property

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that TestContext has to be a public property in order for the framework to set it for you.  Have you tried making it public?

Comment: Also note that the name of the property must be exact - 'TestContext'. Other names, e.g. 'Context' will still cause this property to be null.

Comment: Note that in more recent versions of C#, you can use an auto-implemented property - MSTest does not require you to explicitly declare a backing field.

Does anybody else think that Ian's comment deserves to be edited into the answer?  I don't find it intuitively obvious that the property's name and type most both be TestContext and haven't yet been able to find this in the docs.  And I'm guessing from the upvote count on Ian's comment that at least 5 other people feel this way.

Comment: Why the heck does the variable name have to be the same as the type?